# Should I make constant for values of three choices (trivalent/ternary)?

Tags: java, patterns-and-practices, constants

For two choices there is boolean. In my case, I have positive, negative, and neutral which are three choices and cannot be represented by boolean. I've see there's method `Math.signum(x)` in Java which returns -1, 0, or 1. So, should I follow this practice (simply use -1, 0, 1 without creating constants) or create constants?

```
int type = -1;
// vs
int type = Type.NEGATIVE;
```

Comment: Could you use an Enum?

Comment: I will prefer to define constants, which improves readability. You can also use Enums.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever confronted with the possibility of making your code easier to read with no downsides, you should do so.

Java enums offer the possibility to handle specific values with readable names.  In terms of efficiency, the use of enums is comparable to using integers.  In terms of readability, the representation is clear and unambiguous through use of a label.

```
enum Option {
    OFF,
    ON,
    DEFAULT
}
```

Therefore your code, rather than have:

```
if (opt == 2) {
    // Default option
}
```

You can get:

```
if (opt == Option.DEFAULT) {
    // Default option
}
```

In your case, you'd have:

```
enum SignValue {
    NEGATIVE,
    NEUTRAL,
    POSITIVE
}
```

Comment: This answer is good for Java, however, for C# I would always recommend using a constant or a normal class over an enum.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer Why would enums not be favorable for C#?

Comment: in C# enums are basically procedural constructs, and glorified constants. They lack enough features or power to justify their existence. Sure, they have some justified uses, but they are usually abused.

Comment: I disagree with @TheCatWhisperer. C#'s enums are ideal for this scenario as that are just "glorified constants", which is all that's needed here.

Comment: Is `Math.signum(x)` bad?

Comment: @BornToCode Lets just say the returned value of Math.signum(x) is contextless.  If the behavior of your code is determined on the return value of Math.signum(x), you risk looking back after 6 months and wonder why you were checking if a number was equal to -1.

Comment: @DavidArno Perhaps, for this situation, *currently*. The problem comes when you need more later, such as a long form human readable description.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer, `public static readonly Dictionary<EnumType, string> ... ` problem solved without having to over-engineer the solution now.

Comment: @BornToCode Regarding `Math.signum()`: you run the risk to take its result for an arbitrary integer, and do e.g. addition/subtraction on it, which won't make sense. The `SignValue` enum makes sure that you can't accidentally do nonsense with it.

Comment: @DavidArno It's fine to be against OOP, but why use a OOP language then? I wouldn't exactly call: MyEnum.MyValue.HumanDescription over engineering... you can do this in Java, but not C#

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer, then use Java.

Comment: @DavidArno, you seem to be happy writing procedural code, maybe you should switch to C ;)